# Firebase Cloud messaging can send messages to iOS Application, but not android?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

The status of the message is Completed but I receive nothing on my mobile device.

[image: It detects the application, I think.]

I am pretty sure I have followed the steps perfectly regarding the google.services.json file and adding the required dependancies. The app runs without errors.

It just never receives the notification when I send it from the console.

Let me know if there is any code you want to see.

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

```
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'notifications');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'notifications');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'notifications');
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
  }
```

Comment: How do you handle notifications from Firebase in the app?

Comment: See Edit - I added the code in the main

Comment: Where are you adding Android config for notifications?

Comment: I never did that? Do I have to? I thought the dart code would do both

Comment: Are you added plugin initialization on Android side?